# Azure Virtual Machine cannot resolve DNS entry of Application Gateway

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dns, virtual-machine

I have the following situation:

If I deploy an application (Deployment, Service and Ingress) in my kubernetes cluster, my ingress deployment is being automatically added to my application gateway (I am using the Azure Application Gateway Ingress Controller; https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/annotations/ ). So far so good.
That means that my application can be reached via my application gateway via https://my-app-gateway-public-ip/myAppPath/. Also, I have an additional private DNS zone which makes my app accessible via https://dns-name/myAppPath.

Additionally, we have an AADDS in combination with a Bastion Service. Deployed some virtual machines and the virtual machines use the DNS resolver of the AADDS (for authentication against the AAD).

The problem is: If I am outside of the cloud, I can nslookup the dns or can access the site via the ip, but I cannot do that with my virtual machines. My DNS server (within the AADDS) is unable to resolve the dns or accessing the ip. I am wondering what the issue is.

The bastion and AADDS are in different subscriptions and therefore different virtual networks. I established already a peering between those virtual networks (or the authentication between the AADDS and the VMs wouldn't work).

The kubernetes cluster and the application gateway are also in a different subscription, but no peering has been done so far.

Are there any hints what I could be missing?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

•   Since, you are using a Bastion gateway server to connect to the VMs hosted in your subscription, the **`Bastion gateway server must be having a public IP address through which then the registered underlying VMs can be connected to via private links created in the private DNS zones associated with a particular virtual network in a subnet and an assigned private IP address and a FQDN accordingly`**. Thus, if **you want to access the application website hosted behind the application gateway, then you will have to create a conditional forwarder in the DNS zone in AADDS to redirect the internal requests from the VMs hosted within a virtual network to the public IP address of the website hosted behind the application gateway**

•   Thus, **`a conditional forwarder forwards the DNS resolution requests for a particular resource hosted on the public internet for which the DNS host resolution is not found or done in that DNS zone which usually serves or fulfils the requests related to internal environment`**. As a result, **when a VM configured with a private IP is registered as a host in the internal DNS zone queries the public IP or FQDN associated with the application’s website, the DNS requests are forwarded to the public internet through the conditional forwarder and then the results are displayed in the VM’s browser for the application’s webpage. Thus, the VMs don’t need to have internet access but the DNS server should have or should forward the requests through the Internet proxy server accordingly to reach the internet**.

For more information on creating conditional forwarder in AADDS, kindly refer to the below link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/manage-dns#create-conditional-forwarders***

Comment: I did try this, but it ends with an error which doesn't offer any additional details.
The default forwarder in my aadds is the default azure dns server. If anything fails, this default forwarder should kick in, but it doesn't with this sub-domain. Any sort of delegation added doesn't work either. It is only working if I am adding a static host entry (A) like apps.sub.domain.com, then it can be resolved, but I would rather not have to set any static ip address, since I want to add my entries to the public dns zone via terraform automatically.

Comment: Try to add the 'A' host entry in public DNS zone for the 'apps.sub.domain.com' and add google's DNS servers' IP address in the conditional forwarder in AADDS. This will redirect the requests to public internet via Google's DNS servers and then it will be redirected to the public IP address for the 'A' host record created for the application. This should work.

Comment: The 'A' is already there. It works flawlessly from my private machine. But I cannot add any conditional forwarder to our AADDS.

Comment: That's a thing to understand why you can't add any conditional forwarder to AADDS. Might be you should check the documentation links for that purpose.